# How to automatically correct certain words?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet in which column L has certain roles starting from L2.

These roles must have the correct spelling. For example, if there is a role called "Admin" there must be no other way to fill in the word. For example " Admin" or "Admin " or "admin" or "aDmin" "adMin" "admIn" "admiN". All other possibilities must be corrected to "Admin".

I found:

```
Cells.Replace What:="admin", Replacement:="Admin", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But then I would need to adjust these lines with all other possibilities, so is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: with `MatchCase:=False` you should only need to worry about the ones with spaces in front or behind.  If it is the only word in the cell then `What:="*admin*"` would cover all of them.

Comment: This would also replace admin in administrator for example.  Why not use Data Validation?

Comment: Mmmm thanks, I'm going to check it out brb!

Comment: Data Validation? I have to look into that!

Comment: Another option, than data validation is to add them to the autocorrect. File→Options→Proofing→AutoCorrectOptions.  Though this will need to be done on every version of Excel that this will be used on.  So DataValidation is probably the best option for maintaining.

Comment: Is there something like a tool which can create every possible word combination with one word?

Comment: You could use a drop box so the individual that fills in the sheet can select the role, so the spelling would always be correct.

Comment: That's really a great idea, but too bad this data is going to be imported into another company and their script doesn't like a dropbox, or at least I think the script from the other company will break on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I do is use a table of parameters in a separate sheet and I put in the column A the words that I want to evaluate when comparing it in the table of parameters I enter it in a variable and I apply ucase () to standardize to uppercase in both criteria To evaluate if the word is contained I use the word that is defined in the parameter table and in addition to using trim (), to remove the empty spaces this would be the code.

```
dim PalabraCorrecta as string
dim PalabraEvaluar as string
dim fila, row_yourbook as integer
FILA = 5
row_yourbook = 2
do while YourBook.sheets("YourSheetsname").range("L" & row_yourbook).value <> ""
    do while thisworkbooks.sheets("PARAMETROS").RANGE("A" & FILA).VALUE <> ""
    PalabraCorrecta = thisworkbooks.sheets("PARAMETROS").RANGE("A" & FILA).VALUE
    PalabraEvaluar = YourBook.sheets("YourSheetsname").range("L" & row_yourbook).value
        if instr(1,trim(ucase(PalabraCorrecta)),trim(ucase(PalabraEvaluar)), vbTextCompare) > 0 then
        YourBook.sheets("YourSheetsname").range("L" & row_yourbook).value = PalabraCorrecta
        goto out_parameter
        end if
    FILA = FILA  +1
    loop
out_parameter:
row_yourbook = row_yourbook +1
loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment p_gomez22 I'll check it out a check if this would work.

Comment: Im getting a Syntax error on this line:

if instr(1,trim(ucase(PalabraCorrecta)),trim(ucase(PalabraEvaluar)), > 0 then

Comment: Hello, if you excuse my mistake, I forgot a part of the code, I already corrected it, this line was missing in the validation of the instr ", vbTextCompare)"

Comment: K going to check it out!

Comment: Sorry I was not able to adjust this code to work for me.

Comment: Remember that you have to create a table on the sheet "PARAMETERS" from column A6 onwards with the correct words with the format you need for the loop to go through it and you must change the name of the range your book and your sheet, I put one generic in the code.

Comment: add an escape loop to the code when you find the correct word.

Comment: Ok if your sheet 1 is the book you want to evaluate and the TEST sheet would be your table of parameters in this TEST sheet you must put in column A6 down all the correct words that you are going to accept as valid "Admin" and all the ones you need evaluate down.
I can not comment on the example you put, the rules of the page do not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Do I adjust it like this and then add a Sheet2 and put the words within row A?

```
dim PalabraCorrecta as string
dim PalabraEvaluar as string
dim fila, row_yourbook as integer
FILA = 5
row_yourbook = 2
do while YourBook.sheets("Sheet1").range("L" & row_yourbook).value <> ""
    do while thisworkbooks.sheets("TEST").RANGE("A" & FILA).VALUE <> ""
    PalabraCorrecta = thisworkbooks.sheets("TEST").RANGE("A" & FILA).VALUE
    PalabraEvaluar = YourBook.sheets("Sheet1").range("L" & row_yourbook).value
        if instr(1,trim(ucase(PalabraCorrecta)),trim(ucase(PalabraEvaluar)), vbTextCompare) > 0 then
        YourBook.sheets("Sheet1").range("L" & row_yourbook).value = PalabraCorrecta
        end if
    FILA = FILA  +1
    loop
row_yourbook = row_yourbook +1
loop
```